# How to show Maintenance mode on Uninstall from Program files (install Shield)

Tags: installshield, installscript, installshield-2012

I have created a setup through install shield and the installation goes correctly.

The problem is when I uninstall from program files then I want to display maintenance mode. Presently it directly shows removing and it removes the program.

I do have setup the maintenance dialog so when user tries to re-install then it will take the user to maintenance mode.

I think I can do it  in Install script but I am using normal installation (Basic MSI)

Anyone knows how we can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In a Basic MSI project, setting the [ARPNOREMOVE property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367591.aspx) to 1 disables the <kbd>Uninstall</kbd> button (and its nearly-silent experience). It yields only an <kbd>Uninstall/Change</kbd> button that invokes maintenance. Note that the labels of the buttons may differ on different versions of Windows.

Comment: thanks for the reply. so is there anyway where I can use advanced UI and I can achieve the behavior ? My basic requirement is when user click on uninstall from program and features then I should show a dialog where the user is asked if he needs to remove all the data or not. I think I can show the message box but the dialog is more appropriate.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand this follow up, but let me suggest that you not go that route. Showing UI from the normal Uninstall button would almost definitely break the silent promise of `msiexec /x {...} /qb`. Instead send them down a route that shows UI as I described in my answer.

Comment: I completely understand your approach, but as per our business guidelines we need to show only uninstall in the program and features for removing our application.